# How to keep image on same line as text?

Tags: css, html, image

I am trying to keep the logo of this company on the same line as the title. As you can see in the image, it is below the title ALT and I wish to have it on the right of it.
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpvLG.png)

This is my code,

```css
#fh5co-logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="fh5co-logo"><a href="index.html">ALT<span>.     
         <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" height=100px width=100px title="lab"></span></a></div>
```

Comment: Please provide full CSS and HTML code or jsfiddle.

Comment: Your image is currently inline with the text, if this is not the case in your site, you need to provide all the css that affects this html so we can see what the problem is (or you can, as you enter the separate bits of css it helps you debug each part).  Please take the time to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: try giving `parent` of `image` and  `text` these properties `display:grid;grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;` then just adjust there percentages

Answer (score -1):

You can use flex to accomplish this.

Wrap the text in a span, and apply it to the a element:

```css
#fh5co-logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

#fh5co-logo a{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="fh5co-logo">
  <a href="index.html">
    <span>ALT.</span>
    <img src="https://www.graphicsprings.com/filestorage/images/283/logomakersamples45.png?width=150&height=70&quality=80&crop=0&method=crop" title="lab">
  </a>
</div>
```